# Indexing on a field and "order by" on another field

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-order-by, database-performance

Let's assume I have a small database with three columns : "id1", "id2" and "date".
I am indexing my database on the field "id1" since it is a frequently selected field (many select queries are ran with ex: where "id1" = 125548).

In some particular query I have, I need to sort the records of a user based on the date" field in the table which is not indexed. My curiosity is if the sort operation (which is basically a order-by operation) on the date field will be ran on the whole database or only on the rows of the user (ex: 125548) which I select based on the "id1" field.

Below is an example query:

```
SELECT u 
FROM UserView u 
WHERE u.viewedId=:viewedId AND u.viewDate >=:dateLimit 
ORDER BY u.viewDate DESC
```

Comment: Would be a stupid optimizer if it orders first before it starts to filter the records. All the ordering was a waste of time.

Comment: I thinks so as well, but I read somewhere that this is what is happening.

Comment: You could use EXPLAIN to check how the query will be performed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIrst, you can create an index that will do both, assuming your query really is simple:

```
select . . 
from table t
where id1 = X
order by col2
```

A composite index on `table(id1, col2)` can be used for both the `where` and `order by`.

As for your question.  In general, the filtering will be done first.  There may be some databases that would look at the statistics for the table and say "gosh, half the records have `id1` and I have an index on `col2` -- I'll use the index for the sort".  However, no database would sort *all* the data (as opposed to using an index) and then filter it afterwards.  Sorts are more efficient on smaller amounts of data.

EDIT:

For your query:

```
SELECT u 
FROM UserView u 
WHERE u.viewedId=:viewedId AND u.viewDate >=:dateLimit 
ORDER BY u.viewDate DESC;
```

The optimal index is `UserView(ViewId, viewDate)`.  Assuming that `UserView` is a table (or perhaps a view that only selects from one table), then this index should be used for both the `WHERE` (both clauses) and the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: thanks for the response, creating and index on the date is possible as well but I was thinking maybe it would cost too much space and performance since I do frequent insertions.

Comment: @ralzaul . . . An index with two columns is not going to take much more time for insertions than an index with one column.  It will occupy more space, but you would have to be in a severely space-constrained environment for that to make a difference.

Comment: I see your point, so when we index them together as UserView(ViewId, viewDate) it is still one b-tree anyway am I right?

Comment: It is still one b-tree.